# What is 'covariant variation'?

Tags: variational-principle, gauge-invariance, variational-calculus

What is 'covariant variation'? As opposed to the usual variation with respect to a gauge parameter?

Comment: Hi Jim Stasheff. Welcome to Phys.SE. Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: One of two papers recently by Bonezzi & Hohm.

Comment: Link the paper in the answer (link to the abstract page). Give a reference to the exact paragraph/sentence/equation where the idea comes up (by which I mean copy-paste/explain the discussion surrounding your confusion. As a matter of principle, you should try and provide as much context and reference if you want people to help you. Don't expect anyone to go looking for references to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, Ref. 1 considers generalizations of [Yang-Mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory)-type gauge theories based on a [Leibniz algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_algebra) structure. Concretely, Ref. 1 defines a *covariant variation* as
$$ \Delta {\cal A}~:=~e^{-{\cal A}}\delta e^{\cal A}. \tag{3.33}$$
In physics jargon, ${\cal A}$ is a gauge field; $\Lambda=\delta {\cal A}$ plays the role of an infinitesimal gauge transformation; and $\Delta {\cal A}$ is an infinitesimal covariant gauge transformation.

References:

1. R. Bonezzi & O. Hohm, [arXiv:1910.10399](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10399); eq. (3.33).

Comment: That's a pertinent example but not a definition. Sorry to think like a mathematician.